# Hadoop Map-Reduce OutputFormat for assigning result to in-memory variable (not files)?

Tags: hadoop, io, mapreduce, distributed-objects

(from a Hadoop newbie)

I want to avoid files where possible in a toy Hadoop proof-of-concept example. I was able to read data from non-file-based input (thanks to http://codedemigod.com/blog/?p=120) - which generates random numbers.

I want to store the result in memory so that I can do some further (non-Map-Reduce) business logic processing on it. Essetially:

```
conf.setOutputFormat(InMemoryOutputFormat)
JobClient.runJob(conf);
Map result = conf.getJob().getResult(); // ?
```

The closest thing that seems to do what I want is store the result in a binary file output format and read it back in with the equivalent input format. That seems like unnecessary code and unnecessary computation (am I misunderstanding the premises which Map Reduce depends on?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with this idea is that Hadoop has no notion of "distributed memory". If you want the result "in memory" the next question has to be "which machine's memory?" If you really want to access it like that, you're going to have to write your own custom output format, and then also either use some existing framework for sharing memory across machines, or again, write your own.

My suggestion would be to simply write to HDFS as normal, and then for the non-MapReduce business logic just start by reading the data from HDFS via the FileSystem API, i.e.:

```
FileSystem fs = new JobClient(conf).getFs();
Path outputPath = new Path("/foo/bar");
FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(outputPath);
// read data and store in memory
fs.delete(outputPath, true);
```

Sure, it does some unnecessary disk reads and writes, but if your data is small enough to fit in-memory, why are you worried about it anyway? I'd be surprised if that was a serious bottleneck.

Comment: That makes perfect sense Joe. Thanks. I'll mark the answer as correct after waiting a little while in case more people have any input.